# C# 10 pocket reference Task example does not work for me

Tags: c#, async-await

The following code example from the C# 10 Pocket Reference does not write the expected result in my console (`ubuntu.22.04-x64`, `dotnet 6.0.11`) and I can't tell if I'm missing anything implicit in the book or if the code example is wrong or does not work on all platforms (I am new to C#).

```cs
Task<int> task = ComplexCalculationAsync();
var awaiter = task.GetAwaiter();

awaiter.OnCompleted (() => // Continuation
{
    int result = awaiter.GetResult();
    Console.WriteLine (result); // 116
});

Task<int> ComplexCalculationAsync() => Task.Run ( () => ComplexCalculation() );

int ComplexCalculation()
{
    double x = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++)
    x += Math.Sqrt (x) / i;
    return (int)x;
}
```

I was expecting `116` to be printed to my console when running `dotnet run` from the project folder. Tried to use `dotnet 5.0` but ran into missing GLIBC system dependencies.

Comment: Are you getting an Exception? What result are you getting instead of 116?

Comment: You haven't posted the code that actually awaits the task.  I would guess that is the problem.

Comment: For completeness: `var result = ComplexCalculation(); Console.WriteLine(result);` is enough here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program finishes, before the calculation is finished. You never **actually** wait for the result, you just specify what should happen, when the calculation is done. Therefore the program exits, before anything is printed to the console.

For testing purposes, you can add something to the end of your program, that stops it from exiting. You could for example use `Console.ReadLine()` or `Thread.Sleep(10000)`.

It should however be noted, that using `TaskAwaiter` and `OnCompleted` is generally not the ideal solution. If possible you should use `await`. This would also simplify your code:

```cs
int result = await ComplexCalculationAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result);

Task<int> ComplexCalculationAsync() => Task.Run(() => ComplexCalculation());

int ComplexCalculation()
{
    double x = 2;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100000000; i++)
        x += Math.Sqrt(x) / i;
    return (int)x;
}
```